# VOIP network and Computer Network together

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, voip

I have two networks, my main data network which is a domain controller and my VOIP network for phones.  Both networks have completely seperate hardware (routers,switchs, e.c.t)  I woul like to have the VOIP system connect through a static NIC IP, both servers have DHCP for assignment to devices I do not want the DHCP to bleed over between networks.  Will assigning a static address to a seperate NIC in the VOIP allow this?

Comment: Your main data network is a domain controller?  What do you mean?

Comment: If the two networks are physically separate, there is no way for the DHCP to "bleed over".  Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're asking because it's pretty difficult to tell...

Comment: As an FYI you can run a VOIP system on the same physical hardware as your lan, they're just separated by VLANS...

Comment: I suggest you contact a friend or consultant more experienced in networking. Specifically things like inter-vlan routing, dhcp relay, and switching fundamentals. All will be required to complete what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I see.

Your users and domain contoller server are on one network, and your voip phones and voip server are on another network.

You have DHCP separately on both networks - one to serve the users and one to serve the phones.  You want to be able to access the voip server via a seperate NIC that is connected to the user network.

The answer is "yes" you can do this.  DHCP will not be issued by the voip server onto the data network, provided it is not configured to do so.  You'll want to be careful here of courses, but unless the dhcp has a scope defined for the subnet that the network card is part of, then it wouldn't ordinarily respond to dhcp requests on that network (having no IP addresses to issue).  It is best to just not have it listening on that network to be on the safe side.  How you do this is server dependent.